# Apply map transformation on specific columns while retaining other columns in Scala

Tags: scala, dataframe, select, apache-spark-sql, transformation

I have a map function  which I would like to apply to specific columns in the dataframe . Say I have a dataframe ABC as follows:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| foo | 1 |
| bar | 4 |
| biz | 3 |

I want to multiply all the elements of the column B by 2 while retaining column A to get the output as follows:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| foo | 2 |
| bar | 8 |
| biz | 6 |

I am aware of how I can select the column B in the dataframe and use map to transform the elements as shown in the code below:
`ABC.select("B").columns.map(c => c*2)`

But my problem is that I am unable to get column A as well.

I first tried using something like this:
`ABC.select("A", (ABC.select("B").columns.map(c => c*2):_*)`

However, this throws an error that 'select' method cannot be overloaded - which is fair since it does not accept arguments of the type Array[Column]. I then tried this:

`val arrayB = Array("B")`

`ABC.select(ABC.columns.map(c => if (arrayB.contains(c)) c*2 else col(c)):_*)`

This does work and returns me the result but I wanted to know if there is a better way of doing this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, expr}

ABC.select(col("A"), expr("B * 2").as("B"))
```

You can also use `selectExpr("A, B * 2 as B")` (or even `col("B") * 2` maybe?), but I'd prefer the first one, It's cleaner and easier to maintain.

UPDATE (because of latest comments):
As far as I understood, you may want to apply a specific function to all the columns inside your df, if I'm correct then I would suggest you to do this:

```
import org.apache.spark.{Column, DataFrame}
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

// This is the base function which will be curried //
def applyColumnTransformation(column: Column)(transformation: Column => Column): Column = transformation(column)

val myTransformation: Column => Column = inputColumn => {
    // your logic here, for instance:
    inputColumn * 2  // you can pass name alias here, like (inputColumn * 2).as(inputColumn.toString)
}

def applyMyTransformation(column: Column): Column = applyColumnTransformation(column)(myTransformation)
```

Now you have the all you want, simply do this:

```
val allColumns: Seq[Column] = myDf.columns.map(myDf.col)
val transformedColumns: Seq[Column] = allColumns.map(applymyTransformation)
myDf.select(transformedColumns: _*)
```

By the way, make sure to take a look at `functions` package, it has actually LOTS of useful functions.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer @AminMal. In my question, I have given the example of B but in my actual scenario I have a lot of columns I need to apply the transformation. Would I be able to include map transformation within expr() block mentioned in your answer?

Comment: You're welcome, I'm not sure what you mean by map transformation, but as far as I know, the `expr` function is some kind of magic and you can do anything you want, mathematical expressions, SQL-like type conversions, casting and many many other things. can you tell me what you mean by map transformations?

Comment: By map transformation I mean that I want to execute a function on all of the columns e.g. columns.map(c => myFunction(c)). myFunction in my actual scenario is quite complicated which is why I may not be able to include it within the expr() block itself. Therefore, I want to be able to call function on columns. It need not be a map transformation, but that is the only approach I know to call the same function on multiple columns. Therefore, my question if map can be called within expr() block? Or is there any way to achieve this?